# Vectors - Unit Vectors

Tags: vectors

Find a unit vector, which is parallel to $i+rj+2k$ and also perpendicular to $2i+2j-k.$ I am unsure, how to find a vector, which would be parallel to that vector and also perpendicular.

Comment: Please add what your thoughts are about the question. As it stands the question doesn't fit the rules described in the [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

Comment: not helpful at all

Comment: (1) What property do parallel vectors have?  (2) What happens when you take the dot product of perpendicular vectors?

Answer (score 1):

Let $p(i+rj+2k)$, where $p\neq0$, be our vector.

Thus, $$p(i+rj+2k)(2i+2j-k)=0$$ or
$$p(2+2r-2)=0,$$
 which gives $r=0$ and since $\sqrt{1^2+2^2}=\sqrt5$,

we get the answer: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt5}(i+2k)$$

Comment: how do you know that they are parallel